# Load capacitance estimation for compensation of switching power supplies

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, capacitance, stability

I'm calculating a compensation network for power supplies based on the [LM20323MH](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm20323.pdf) from TI.

I have slight doubts about correct estimation of output capacitance to use in the calculation. The board is a CPU motherboard (i.mx6q quad core, 1.4 GHz) so there is a lot of distributed capacitance around the board, bigger then the output caps for the switcher itself.

Should I account for all the capacitance across the board or just the capacitors close to and associated to the power supply. I do not have much insight at the moment into how the capacitance separated some distance away plays into the stability of the switchers.

So the question is: Should I account for all capacitance seen by the output of the switchers or just the capacitors close to and associated with the switcher?

Intuition tells me that I should account for the total board capacitance since there will likely be a low impedance connection to the distributed capacitors via power planes, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Is this a POL supply located on the cpu board, or a separate supply with distribution cable?

Comment: It's located on the board. The board is a industrial embedded CPU which operates from 24V. So the switcher in question is 24V -> 3.3V which powers a PMIC which creates the rest of the system voltages, it also powers various 3.3V peripherals. The 3.3V power rail has significant amount of distributed capacitance around the board so the question revolves around what capacitance value to use in the calculation of the feedback network. The total 3.3V network capacitance or just the main capacitors associated to and close to the switcher.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LM20323 is a current mode control switcher, so you should only have to worry about the pole caused by the equivalent load resistance (\$R_L\$) and the total output capacitance (\$C_o\$).  There is a lot that is not known here and I am going to make some simple minded guesses about the situation.

- The board is a multilayer PCB, about 5"x8" with 60mil separation between ground plane and +3.3V plane.  \$Z_o\$ for the power planes would be less than 2 Ohms, and inductance across the span of the board would be less than ~3nH.
- Loop bandwidth of the +3.3V supply will be less than 10kHz.

With a board like that and with relatively low loop frequency, capacitor esr will dominate.  Yes the loop will see the total distributed capacitance that is connected directly across the +3.3V plane to ground.  You should put the compensation zero in the error amp to cover that pole formed by the total distributed \$C_o\$ and \$R_L\$.

**Some other things you should think about:**

- It is kind of unusual to have more capacitance distributed rather than at the supply output (at least I think it is).  Say half of the capacitance is distributed.  That means that half of the 500kHz ripple current (like 300mA or so) is also distributed.  Is that going to meet the system EMI requirement?  It is pretty common to have a secondary filter in place to reduce the ripple.  A (adequately damped) secondary filter can keep the ripple currents confined in a small loop area to reduce EMI.
- If the PMIC being supplied by this 3.3V output is a switcher itself, have you looked at output impedance to input impedance relationship between the two?  Switching regulators have negative input impedance.  Unless the source supply has lower output impedance than the input impedance of the load switchers the system can oscillate.  It is best to have source output impedance about 1/2 the load input impedance.  This kind of oscillation can even happen between the input filter of the switcher and the switcher being filtered.

Comment: Very interesting post. Your assumptions are good. It's a 8 layer board with 4 gnd/power planes. The capacitance for the switcher tends to go down with frequency so the ratio between distributed decoupling and switcher output capacitance may result in equal amount on each side. But then again the need for bulk decoupling in my case may be overestimated but unfortunately we don't want to buy expensive software to optimize that part so too much is better then too little to some extent. The EMI perspective is definitely something i need to think about.

Comment: The PMIC is actually 6 switchers, and 5 LDOs in a single package, the PMIC and 3.3V switcher are close to each other with output/input connected with a solid copper plane. This is one reason for the sizeable 3.3V power capacitance. Could you identify some particularly good or bad scenarios depending on the output impedance to input impedance ratio of 3.3V switcher and the PMIC ?

Comment: That sounds like some IC, 6 switchers + 5 LDOs. Is it custom?  Edited answer to add a little about source impedance.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. The PMIC is a chip freescale makes to ease the power generation for the i.mx6 processor.
http://cache.freescale.com/files/analog/doc/data_sheet/MMPF0100.pdf